# Excel data for every Xth cell

Tags: excel, row, cell

Is it possible for me to automaticly enter data from one column to every Xth row?

I have one row of data which I would like to eneter to Xth row in the same column and dont want to do it manually.

For exaple 50 cells of data in one row and I would like to enter one cell of this data to another row but on every lets say 10th cell.

Comment: Yes quite right.  I've moved it - I'm quite confident I can help with this. Do you have a spreadsheet with some sample data ?

Comment: Not overly sure what you're after without some sample data.  Maybe `=IFERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & TEXTJOIN(REPT("</s><s>",10),FALSE,$C$1:$I$1) & "</s></t>","//s"),"")` which will take a single row of data and put it in a column with blank cells between.